# How to give spaces in image grid using HTML / Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, dom, ejs

I'm making an image grid.

```
<div class="row text-center" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <% campgrounds.forEach(function(campground) { %>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="<%= campground.image%>">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4><%= campground.name %></h4> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>          
        <% }); %> 
    </div>
```

The output I get is [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7DOr.jpg). There is no spacing between images. How to add it? I'm not using any CSS at the moment.

Comment: Just add padding to the div thumbnail class.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using lastest boostrap you can use:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">...</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: I'm using the latest bootstrap, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

that `display: flex` is not necessary. You can add a padding at the div with thumbnail class:
in a css file

```css
.thumbnail {
    padding: 8px;
}
```

or

```
...
<div class="thumbnail" style="padding: 8px">
   ...
</div>
...
```

Comment: can we do it without using any additional css? Also this doesn't seem to work. The images are still there without any space (even after increasing padding).

Comment: try to add `display:block` to img tag, and a `width: 100%`